# Trying to deploy a ReactJS project using FirebaseCLI

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a ReactJS app I built that works locally , I followed the instructions on the Firebase site

```
https://medium.com/@devesu/host-a-react-based-website-free-of-cost-with-firebase-hosting-and-connect-with-your-own-domain-53146731807f
```

and everything went to plan ,inthat there were no errors however when I follow the link provided

```
https://hydrometric-54ec0.web.app
```

or

```
https://hydrometric-54ec0.firebaseapp.com/
```

I get a default Firebase page and not my app, I think my firebase.json is missing something here it is below

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is in your build directory that you deployed?

Comment: Hey Doug I had my build environment but my index html was being overwritten by the default firebase one ...all good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying any **React** project in **Firebase**. look for the below steps.

- Once the react build is done through `npm run build`
- Do `firebase init`
- Select Hosting
- Then  CLI will ask for public directory- Write `build` and hit enter.
- rewrite all urls to /index.html- Type `Yes`
- File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?- Type `No` or else it will overwrite your index file with firebase default index.

Before `firebase deploy` do the following things.
Replace this code in `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then inside your react `package.json`
do blank path for `homepage`

- `"homepage": ""`

Now yor are good to go for `firebase deploy`

Comment: Welcome @R.Merritt